# Symfony Messenger 4.3 - Consuming messages from doctrine transport fails (exception thrown)

Tags: symfony, symfony-4.3, symfony-messenger

Symfony version: `4.3.2`

PHP: `7.2.20`

I am trying to use the messenger component with the doctrine transport asynchronously. I have installed the messenger via `composer require messenger` with the help of Symfony Flex.

I have activated the doctrine transport by `MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=doctrine://default` in the `.env.local`.
In the messenger config the transport is configured as well:

```
framework:
    messenger:   
        transports:
            async: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
        routing:
            'App\Message\SomeNotification': async
```

When dispatching the message in the controller with `$this->dispatchMessage(new SomeNotification('some content'));` everything is fine. The table `messenger_messages` of the doctrine transport gets created automatically and the message is saved in the table correctly.

When trying to consume the message with `./bin/console messenger:consume async` I'm getting the following error:

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Component\Messenger\Worker::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\Messenger\MessageBusInterface, string given, called in ..../vendor/symfony/messenger/  
  Command/ConsumeMessagesCommand.php on line 190
```

So the $routableBus in the `Symfony\Component\Messenger\Command\ConsumeMessagesCommand` is empty which leads to the crash when instantiating the Worker.

Comment: The problem is likely that your transport referenced under `failure_transport` does not exist. Just copy the `transport: async` as `failed` and possible add a queue name `failed: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%?queue_name=failed'`

Comment: @dbrumann I'm sorry this was a copy and paste error of the messenger config. I have corrected it in the question. It still doesn't work. (same exception)

Comment: Could it be that you accidentally misconfiguried the Message Bus in your service configuration? Could you run `bin/console debug:container 'Symfony\Component\Messenger\MessageBusInterface'` and check that it is in fact a service based on MessageBus?

Comment: Hmm to be honest I've just done the steps in the documentation. Here is what I'm getting with the debug command: https://gist.github.com/DenisMir/53a166187768fa252665be07891a68c1 
When I'm interpreting it correctly I think that the bus is configured correctly. If that wasn't the case I would expect the dispatch to fail as well.

Comment: Yes, that looks correct. I have not encountered this before, but I am rarely using the Doctrine transport. Maybe I have time tomorrow to see if I can reproduce this issue, if no one else finds a solution until then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for the question is to update `symfony/framework-bundle` to `4.3.2` as well. Due to a bug in the `composer.json` of the messenger component version `4.3.2` of the framework bundle is not enforced. This leads to the default misconfiguration when using an older version of the `symfony/framework-bundle` in combination with `4.3.2` of the messenger component. This explained my error since I had `4.3.0` of the framework bundle installed.

More about it can be found on the GitHub issue tracker right here:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/32738

After updating the `symfony/framework-bundle` everything works as expected.